# How to send data to parent component using v-slot in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, parent-child

I am trying to use slot-scopes in my component but I am not really successful on these. So in general what I am trying to do is I have a parent component and as a slot I am sending another component (child-component). In child component there is a button which changes the boolean.

So child component is:

```
<button @click="changeEditMode">Change edit mode</c-button>

methods: {
   changeEditMode() {
      this.$emit('edit-mode', true);
    },
}
```

Parent component:

```
<div>
        <slot :edit-mode="editMode"></slot>
      </div>

props: {
    editMode: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

And here where both of them exist:

```
<parent-component>
              <template v-slot="scope">
                {{ scope.editMode }}
                <child-component
                  @edit-mode="scope.editMode"
                />
              </template>
            </parent-component>

    data() {
        return {
          editMode: false,
        };
      },
```

So I am expecting the value of {{ scope.editMode }} will change when I click the button but nothing changes. So where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to update the `editMode` variable in your third component then you don't need to use scoped slot. Simply use `named slots` and you can update the data like this-

**Parent component-**
Give your slot a name "scope" where you are planning to inject the data.

```
<div>
  <slot name="scope"></slot>
</div>
```

**Another component-**
Put your child component inside the named slot of the parent and simply listen to the emitted event from the child and update your `editMode` variable.

```
<parent-component>
  <template #scope>
    {{ editMode }}
    <child-component
      @edit-mode="editMode = $event"
    />
  </template>
</parent-component>

data() {
  return {
    editMode: false,
  };
},
```

Now, as in the question you are passing data to the slots (which I feels less required according to your use case), you can do it like this-

**Parent component-**

```
<div>
  <slot :editMode="editMode"></slot>
</div>

data() {
  return {
    editMode: false,
  }
}
```

**Another component-**

```
<parent-component>
  <template #scope="scopeProps">
    {{ scopeProps }}
  </template>
</parent-component>
```

To know more about the named slots and pass data to named slots, read here- https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots